Contextually and Semantically, Are the Terms 'Us, We, and Saints' (Rom 8:26-27) Referring to Those Already Saved for Whom the Holy Spirit Intercedes?
Contextually and semantically, Romans 8:26-30 functions as a cohesive unit in which Paul addresses a specific group of people. He first identifies them as those for whom the Holy Spirit intercedes in their weakness (vv. 26-27) and later as those 'who love God' (v. 28). However, key terms like "foreknew," "predestined," "called," "justified," and "glorified" are taken by Calvinists as major support for God's sovereign choice in salvation, a core element of the TULIP framework. This necessitates revisiting the passage to understand these terms in their context. The following sub-questions explore these aspects more deeply:

Does the phrase "predestined to be conformed to the image of His Son" in Romans 8:29 refer to believers' future sanctification and glorification, or does it imply predestination to initial salvation?

In Romans 8:30, does the reference to "those predestined" connect back to the idea of being conformed to Christ’s image in verse 29, or specifically to salvation?

In the sequence of Romans 8:30 ("predestined, called, justified, glorified"), are about the believer's final glorification, or does it include the initial act of being saved?


Text: Romans 8:26 -30 (NET)

Likewise the Spirit helps us in our weakness. For we do not know what
to pray for as we ought, but the Spirit himself intercedes for us with
groanings too deep for words. 27And he who searches hearts knows what
is the mind of the Spirit, becauseg the Spirit intercedes for the
saints according to the will of God. 28And we know that for those who
love God all things work together for good,h for those who are called
according to his purpose. 29For those whom he foreknew he also
predestined to be conformed to the image of his Son, in order that he
might be the firstborn among many brothers. 30And those whom he
predestined he also called, and those whom he called he also
justified, and those whom he justified he also glorified.


This was the matter discussed at the great council of Dort in 1618-1619 and has plagued the church ever since and cause immense division.

Contextually and semantically, the terms 'us,' 'we,' and 'saints' in Romans 8:26-27 refer to believers who are already saved. Paul is addressing a specific group of Christians—both Jewish and Gentile—who are indwelt by the Holy Spirit, and for whom the Spirit intercedes. In this passage, Paul emphasizes the ongoing role of the Holy Spirit in helping believers in their weakness, guiding them according to God's will.
1. Overview of Paul's Audience:
Paul's letter to the Romans addresses three main groups within the church:

Believing Jews (Romans 2:1-29; 3:1-8; 4; 9:1-5):
Paul corrects legalistic thinking among Jewish Christians, showing that both Jews and Gentiles need the gospel, and no one can claim righteousness by heritage or the Law alone.
Gentile Believers (Romans 1:5-6; 11:13-24; 15:14-21):
Paul emphasizes the inclusion of Gentiles in God’s plan and urges them to maintain humility in their standing, recognizing that God’s salvation is for all.
Both Jews and Gentile Believers (Romans 1:16-17; 3:9-20; 8-11; 12-15):
Paul stresses the unity of the gospel and the fact that all are under sin and in need of God’s grace. His message also highlights the hope of future restoration and glorification for all who believe.

Summary: Paul’s letter prepares the Roman church for his visit by laying out core doctrines of salvation, addressing both Jewish believers’ legalistic tendencies and Gentile inclusion.
2. Romans 8:26-27 – The Referents Are Saints:
In Romans 8:26-27, Paul speaks specifically to believers who have the Holy Spirit and are called 'saints.' This passage is part of his broader teaching on life in the Spirit, which contrasts with life under the flesh. The Holy Spirit helps believers in their weakness and intercedes for them according to God's will.
Paul’s use of 'us,' 'we,' and 'saints' refers to those already saved, meaning the context of this passage addresses believers and their spiritual growth, not predestination to salvation.
3. Romans 8:26-30: Shifting Paradigm on Predestination
1). Predestined to Be Conformed to the Image of His Son (v. 29):
The phrase "predestined to be conformed to the image of His Son" means that God set His will for believers to become like Christ. This refers to future sanctification and glorification, not initial salvation.
Key Point: As "all" in the Bible does not always mean everyone, it would be incorrect to assume "predestined" always refers to doctrinal predestination. Here, Paul refers to believers' future transformation, not predestination for salvation.
2). Those Predestined" in Romans 8:30:
The term 'predestined' in verse 30 connects back to being conformed to Christ’s image in verse 29, emphasizing believers' transformation into Christ’s likeness, not their election to salvation.
3). Predestined, Called, Justified, Glorified (v. 30):
These terms describe the process by which God brings believers to their final glorification. The sequence highlights their transformation and the assurance of glorification, rather than laying out an ordo salutis focused on conversion.
Conclusion:
Romans 8:26-30 is not primarily a passage about predestination to salvation (as taught by Reformed theology). Rather, it addresses God’s will for believers’ spiritual transformation and future glorification. Paul’s focus is on the assurance that the Holy Spirit works in the lives of those already saved, interceding according to God’s will and guiding them toward their final glorified state.
